# Heatsink Installation - Thermal/Insulating Materials

Tags: hardware-failure, laptop-repair, repair

I need to install a heatsink, but other then the thermal paste it has some sort of black rubberish material.

I think it's an insulation material to protect the exposed pins.
Or maybe it's thermal tape/pads?
(The related image is attached)

- Update:
  It seems there are 3 types of material used: thermal paste, termal pads, and that black thing.
  I also found a video where a guy uses an electrical tape to cover the pins. 
  I guess the black thing on my heatsink is some sort of electial insulation, but I cannot find this product online to confirm.

[image]

Comment: I'm just horrified at a blue heatsink, meaning there's no direct metal to metal contact :<

Comment: This was an expensive motherboard. I think Asus.

Comment: It actually recomended to anodize the heatsinks. Obviously it's more expensive, but it's non-conductive, and increases the surface area .... And aluminum will oxidize regardless, so there is no negative impact.